# Fractional Regression Model in Unbalanced Panel Data

Tags: panel-data, econometrics

My dependent variable is an index that lies within the range [0, 1]. I did a Tobit RE specification. However, I attempt to compare the parameter estimates with that of the method of the fractional regression model.

Papke and Wooldridge (2008) method is applicable when dealing with balanced panels. However, in 2010, Wooldridge develops the correlated random effects model for unbalanced data.

As an alternative, can I use the pooled fracreg model while incorporating cross-section and time dummy in the model specification?

Many Thanks,

Sagnik